# TYPO3: Ext:news – Single Site image always at the bottom

Tags: typo3, tx-news

TYPO3 7.6.23 and Ext: news 6.1.1

When a single site being displayed WITH special content e.g. "Pictures" the image that is usually displayed next to the text is then being displayed at the very bottom under the e.g. "Pictures" Content Element. I could't find anything about that "problem" and wonder if nobody cares ~:-/!

Can anybody give me a hint or a link to solve that display problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit at last. You need the file "Detail.html" ext/news/Resources/Private/Templates/News/Detail.html Look for line 91 and following

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.contentElements}">
    <!-- content elements -->
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering">{newsItem.contentElementIdList}</f:cObject>
</f:if>
<f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: newsItem.media, settings:settings}" />

<!-- main text -->
<div class="news-text-wrap" itemprop="articleBody">
    <f:format.html>{newsItem.bodytext}</f:format.html>
</div>
</n:renderMedia>
```

and change the order to

```
<f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: newsItem.media, settings:settings}" />

<!-- main text -->
<div class="news-text-wrap" itemprop="articleBody">
    <f:format.html>{newsItem.bodytext}</f:format.html>
</div>

<f:if condition="{newsItem.contentElements}">
    <!-- content elements -->
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering">{newsItem.contentElementIdList}</f:cObject>
</f:if>

</n:renderMedia>
```

I really do not understand why this is NOT default!
Hope this might help somebody :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss an evaluation of the field giving the orientation. 
Depending on your rendering: with typoscript (CSC) or fluid templates (FSC) you have to look for the rendering and of images and whether the oriantation is involved.

Comment: I use CSC and I do have that issue on two sides where I have installed news. As soon as there is a additional Content the News image is beeing displayed under that additional content. The text remains at the start of the article.

Comment: I think you should have a look into your news templates. they use fluid where conditions can be used to decide where content is shown. (e.g. if additional CEs are used the images are no longer displayed at the top but in the news footer). Also CSS is involved which can position the image related to another element. You might provide some links to your pages (one to a news article without CEs, one with CEs) or provide some screenshots at least.

Comment: Thank you .. It looks better now :-) - deleted the old posting